# Ethernet only works when PC booted with cable plugged in

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-interface

My Ethernet adapter is `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)` and I'm using x64 Arch Linux, kernel 3.18.4. Connections are managed using NetworkManager.

If I boot/reboot the PC with the Ethernet cable plugged in, no problem, I get an IP address and can use it normally.

But if I boot with the Ethernet cable disconnected and then plug it in, I get the `link up` message in dmesg, but I am unable to get an IP address because DHCP times out.

In both cases I'm using the same cable and the same router (a TP-Link TL-WR740N).

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Retry the DHCP request?  Try using a static IP address?

Comment: @psusi None of them work: the DHCP request just keeps timing out and setting an IP address manually gives "Network is unreachable" even when pinging my router.

Comment: Sounds like a busted router then.  You might fire up `wireshark` and see if any packets are being received.

Comment: @psusi the router works for wireless; also, as I said, when I boot up the PC with the Ethernet cable in, it works normally. I will play with wireshark to see what comes out.